# Angular2 dependency injection vs @ViewChild

Tags: angular

I am wondering what the difference between using dependency injection component and @ViewChild. The both ways I can use the parent attributes methods. So, when I should one and other?

**Dependency Injection**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CompB } from './compb/compb.component';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'app-test',
    templateUrl: 'compA.html'
})
export class CompAComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private _compB: CompB) {
    }
    ngOnInit() {
       this._compB.getName();
    }

}

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'app-test',
    templateUrl: 'compB.html'
})
export class CompBComponent {
    getName() {
       return 'Hello World';
    }
}
```

**@ViewChild**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CompB } from './compb/compb.component';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'app-test',
    templateUrl: 'compA.html'
})
export class CompAComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild(CompB) compB: CompB
    ngOnInit() {
       this._compB.getName();
    }

}

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'app-test',
    templateUrl: 'compB.html'
})
export class CompBComponent {
    getName() {
       return 'Hello World';
    }
}
```

As you can see, the both methods I have access to the getName() in compBComponent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the names should be obvious enough...

`@ViewChild` gives you the reference to an actual view child created inside your view. The lifetime of the child totally depends on the lifetime of current component.

`Injectable component` returns you the object of the specified class (that appears to be a component) which was created by Angular's DI module. The lifetime of this object will be managed by Angular's DI rule (which `providers array` you put this in).

In your example, there's no difference, because a `Component` can be an injectable object, and your `getName` function more likely belongs to a service, not component. `Component` is designed to be a visible module that displays info to users or takes info back from them. Let's take another example, where you have an input in your `compBComponent` that allows user to input the new name, and `getName` will be out of context without user's input. In this case, DI `compBComponent` will become irrelevant.

Plunker to play with (Updated to Final): http://plnkr.co/edit/dn9CiGUrswW2FQgLPWwW

Comment: Thank you for your clarification! It is clear now how and when should use it! Cheers.

Comment: Just did. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

with **@viewChild** u have to do nothing and it will give you current instance of child at each point of time.

With **Dependency Injection**...we have to explicitly add providers for child in parent and this will provide instance of child on first time load only..no change detection happens.

***---Parent component----***

```
import { ChildComponent } from './../child/child.component';
import { AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css'],
  //providers: [ChildComponent]
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(ChildComponent) _child: ChildComponent;
  constructor(
    //private _child: ChildComponent
  ) { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this._child.getName());
  }
  getChildName() {
    console.log(this._child.getName());
  }
}
<app-child></app-child>
<button (click)="getChildName()">Get Child</button>
```

***---child component---***

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  public name = 'sama';
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  getName() {
    return this.name;
  }
  setName(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name">
```